# Show button in relativelayout

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I'm having problems adding a button to my app using relative layout.When I use the graphical layout tool it shows up when i drag and drop the button but when I compile and run the apk on the emulator only the original 'sms' button is there.The new button should of been to the left of the 'sms' button

[image]

and here's the code from the xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF000000" >

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edit_message_input"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:hint="@string/edit_message_input"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:background="#ff000000"
       android:textColor="#CCCCCC"


        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="@string/translate_to_english"
        android:onClick="sendToEnglish"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"



         />



   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/translate_to_text"
        android:onClick="sendToText"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
       android:ems="10"
       android:hint="@string/edit_message_output"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:background="#ff000000"
       android:textColor="#CCCCCC" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
       android:background="#CCCCCC"
       android:onClick="sendSMS"
       android:text="@string/send_as_sms" />

<!-- test save button -->

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/save_word_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:background="#cccccc"
       android:text="@string/save_word" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help or pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell how you want to show all of this. Thanks

Comment: Basically i want a button to the left of the 'sms' button you can see in the screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I suggest you head over to the android developer docs and spend some time reading the recommendations on designing interfaces.

Two particularly useful sections are:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

You have a number of fixed dimensions in your xml and conflicting alignment attributes which appear to be causing a few problems.

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume what ever you design in XML layout will looks nice in every device, because there are wide range of android devices out in market.

Don't take fixed height/width layout if you want to support multiple screens.

```
 android:layout_width="150dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
```

Instead, you can mention "wrap_content" or "fill_parent".

Comment: Thanks Paresh..do you think that is what could be causing the new button not to appear on the emulator?